# Replace Inline JSON with a getJSON Call

Tags: jquery, getjson

I am new to `jQuery` and `javascript` and this is probably a beginner's question.

I am using a javascript quiz library [SlickQuiz](https://github.com/QuickenLoans/SlickQuiz) to make quizzes. The quiz uses the following callback to populate the page

```
$(function () {
    $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({json: {YOUR_JSON_HERE}});
});
```

I want to place the quiz json in a separate file and use `$.getJSON` to pass it. I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('path/to/json', function(quizJSON){
     $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz()
  });
});
```

I have posted it as an issue on `github`, but thought it might be a trivial `jQuery` novice issue and am posting it here.

Comment: And `$('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({json: quizJSON});` in the callback doesn't work..?

Comment: Not able to get it working using the suggested approach. See my comment below to arxanas

Answer (score 2):

Pass the JSON as a parameter to the quiz function:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('path/to/json', function(quizJSON){
     $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({
         json: quizJSON // <--
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Is there a way I can first check to see if the JSON file is getting read correctly. I confirmed that it is valid JSON by copy-pasting it in place of quizJSON, and it works. But when I do the `getJSON` call it does not. Any ideas?

Comment: In your callback, log the JSON: `function(quizJSON) { console.log(quizJSON); ... }`. It will end up telling you whether the JSON is being read correctly.

Comment: There seems to be a problem reading the JSON. Nothing is displayed when I load the page. I also tried `alert(success)`, but no popup is shown. Wonder what could be going wrong.

Comment: I have the json file in the same folder. Could the problem be that I am opening the html file offline as localhost?

Comment: @Ramnath Are you running a server or using `file:///`? The latter will not let you AJAX other files.

Comment: I am using `file:///`. That is the problem then. Is there an alternate way to do read a JSON file in such situations?

Comment: A preliminary examination on my system seems to show that JSONP works. http://json-p.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('path/to/json', function(quizJSON){
     // you need to pass the json to your quiz function
     $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({json: quizJSON});
  });
});
```